# Need to Implement User Driven Crop in iOS app

Tags: ios, image-processing

Is it possible to implement the iOS 5 > 'Photos' app cropping mechanism? This is exactly what I need for my app. I need to allow a user to pick an image and crop that photo using something like what the 'Photos' app provides. Is there a library for this? Can I hook directly to it from the SDK? What are my options here? I have looked through Google and Github with no luck.

Comment: Although the subject of your question is on-topic for stack overflow, you haven't described any effort to solve your problem yourself.  We expect you to do your own research before asking a question like this.  Please edit your question to describe what you've done to solve the problem.  What search terms have you used on Google (or Bing or whatever) to find an answer, and what hits did you investigate?  What documentation have you read?  Have you written any code to try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The standard SDK provides a way to get a picture, let the user crop it, and import it into your App, See:  http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html

Comment: Yes I did look into this and found that it does not use the iOS 5 crop mechanism found in the photos app. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just make sure you set the allowsEditing property of UIImagePickerController to true and you'll want to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol, which gives your App information about the edits made.  This requires iOS 3.1 or later.